# Doctrine 2: Use default 0 values instead of null for relation

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is it possible to use the value 0 instead of null for relations (many-to-one, one-to-one) with Doctrine 2?

Now I've got a lot of NOT NULL columns witch I may not change to null values. 
Changing the default value in MySQL to 0 it self isn't the solution becease doctrine always sets the column for inserting/updating rows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

`NULL` has a very specific meaning in SQL. It represents "no value", and you can verify that your logic won't work even at SQL level:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
    `id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `bar_id` INT(11)
);

CREATE TABLE `bar` (`id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT);

ALTER TABLE foo ADD FOREIGN KEY `bar_id_fk` (`bar_id`) REFERENCES `bar` (`id`);

INSERT INTO `bar` VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO `bar` VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO `bar` VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO `foo` VALUES (NULL, 1);
INSERT INTO `foo` VALUES (NULL, 2);
INSERT INTO `foo` VALUES (NULL, 3);
INSERT INTO `foo` VALUES (NULL, 0);

/*
    ERROR 1452 (23000): 
        Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
        (`t2`.`foo`, CONSTRAINT `foo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`bar_id`) 
        REFERENCES `bar` (`id`))
*/

INSERT INTO `foo` VALUES (NULL, 4);

/*
    ERROR 1452 (23000): 
        Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
        (`t2`.`foo`, CONSTRAINT `foo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`bar_id`) 
        REFERENCES `bar` (`id`))
*/

INSERT INTO `foo` VALUES (NULL, NULL); /* VALID! */
```

So no, you cannot have Doctrine ORM behave so that `0` is interpreted as `NULL`, since that's not allowed by the RDBMS itself.

What you can do is inserting "fake" referenced entries in your DB, which will then act as [null object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) when hydrated as entities:

```sql
INSERT INTO `bar` VALUES (NULL);
UPDATE `bar` SET `id` = 0 WHERE `id` = 4;

INSERT INTO `foo` VALUES (NULL, 0); /* now works! */
```

In entity terms, it looks quite similar.

(Please note that `public` properties are ONLY supported from Doctrine ORM 2.4, which is not yet released. They make things easier to read here, though)

Foo.php:

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo")
 */
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bar")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bar_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    public $bar;
}
```

Bar.php:

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="bar")
 */
class Bar
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;
}
```

And then the code to produce a new `Foo` instance:

```php
$nullBar  = $entityManager->find('Bar', 0);
$foo      = new Foo();
$foo->bar = $nullBar;

$em->persist($foo);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: I know it's bad, but we just used a `postLoad` event to set zero valued fk's  to `null`. Seems to work. see response below for code.